Selenium webdriver - Unable to obtain browser driver
I am new to Selenium, I wrote JS to run my first script.
I ran through all of the set up:
npm init -y
npm install --save selenium-webdriver chromedriver geckodriver
I wrote the following script:
const {By, Key, Builder} = require("selenium-webdriver");

async function test_case() {
    let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();

    await driver.get("https://google.com");
    await driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Hello, World!", Key.RETURN);

    setInterval(function() {
        driver.quit();
    }, 10000);
}

test_case();

I then tried to execute the script using

node test.js

It throws an error: "Error: Unable to obtain browser driver."
Here is my package.json:
{
  "name": "golf",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "chromedriver": "^124.0.1",
    "geckodriver": "^4.4.0",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^4.20.0"
  }
}


So, I figured out what was going on. My anti-virus was removing the .exe when I loaded the webdrivers:
npm install --save selenium-webdriver chromedriver geckodriver

Created the drivers without the .exe.
To resolve this, I turned off my anti-virus and re-ran the same command.
